# Assigning to reference parameter invalidates object

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

I've faced some misleading issue. I have a function which takes string as a reference, splits it using regex, saves one part back to given string and returns the other. However assigning one match to the reference parameter seems to invalidate match object (looks like kind of misused move assignment), while assigning it to a local variable works fine. Here's the code:

```
std::string ParseVar(std::string & szExp)
{
    static std::regex oRegex("^([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]*)\\s*<-\\s*(.+)$");
    std::smatch oMatch;

    if (std::regex_match(szExp, oMatch, oRegex))
    {
        if (oMatch.size() != 3)
            throw std::runtime_error("internal error");

        std::cout << "Match before: " << oMatch.str(2) << std::endl;
        szExp = oMatch.str(2);
        std::cout << "Match after: " << oMatch.str(2) << std::endl;
        return oMatch.str(1);
    }

    return "";
}
```

This prints (for szExp = "foo <- 5+5+5+5"):

```
Match before: 5+5+5+5
Match after:  +5+5+5
```

Returned value also seems to be broken, however szExp contains proper string.

Changing it to:

```
std::string ParseVar(std::string & szExp)
{
    static std::regex oRegex("^([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]*)\\s*<-\\s*(.+)$");
    std::smatch oMatch;
    std::string save1, save2;

    if (std::regex_match(szExp, oMatch, oRegex))
    {
        if (oMatch.size() != 3)
            throw std::runtime_error("internal error");

        save1 = oMatch.str(1);
        save2 = oMatch.str(2);

        std::cout << "Match before: " << oMatch.str(2) << std::endl;
        szExp = save2;
        std::cout << "Match after: " << oMatch.str(2) << std::endl;
        return save1;
    }

    return "";
}
```

Prints the same thing, but at least both returned value and szExp are fine.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std::smatch` object is an instantiation of the `std::match_results` template. Its entry on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results) contains the following passage:

> This is a specialized allocator-aware container. It can only be
>   default created, obtained from std::regex_iterator, or modified by
>   std::regex_search or std::regex_match. Because std::match_results
>   holds std::sub_matches, each of which is a pair of iterators into the
>   original character sequence that was matched, **it's undefined behavior
>   to examine std::match_results if the original character sequence was
>   destroyed or iterators to it were invalidated for other reasons**.

Because modifying the original string (which is what you're doing by assigning to to `szExp`) invalidates iterators into its character sequence, you're falling foul of the above and causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: @PKua yes copying the strings to the save variables does indeed make entirely independent copies. However it is not those copies you're outputting - rather you make the call to `oMatch.str()` again (on your `std::cout` lines)

Comment: The thing to remember is that `oMatch` remains dependent on `szExp` throughout its lifetime. Any call to `oMatch.str()` does produce an independent string, but later repeated calls still need `szExp` not to be invalidated

Comment: I noticed that szExp is my original string and thus modifying it invalidates iterators after I posted a comment, so I deleted it (because the question was actually quite stupid after your answer).

For those who will read it in future: the question in comment was "does `oMatch.str()` create a copy of pointed part of the original string?".

Anyway, now I can (hopefully) understand everything. Thanks a lot.